# Подгрузка View-элементов

Tags: java, android, xml, view

На активности сложная XML-разметка, загрузка которой занимает несколько секунд. Пока это происходит, весь интерфейс зависает, что логично, потому что я подгружаю всю разметку в одном основном потоке.

Суть такая. Хочу добавить экран загрузки с прогрессбаром.

**Вопрос:** как сделать так, чтобы экран загрузки не зависал вместе со всем остальным в процессе подгрузки всей XML-разметки?

Спасибо.

Comment: Скорее всего с разметкой большие проблемы. Если очень нужно можно использовать фрагмент и грузить для него view в отельном потоке.

Comment: Здравствуйте, nekaneka. Можно поподробнее про загрузку View в отдельном потоке?

Comment: Ну можно сделать контейнер на activity и через layoutInflater грузить нужную разметку. Но скорее всего с разметкой очень большие проблемы если она грузится несколько минут, лучше попробовать переделать разметку.

Comment: Спасибо, как попробую — отпишусь.

p.s. Вы неправильно прочитали: "подвисание несколько секунд", а не минут :) Если конкретно, то на моём планшете около двух секунд.

Comment: Как вы хотите решить вашу проблему? Если вы решили оставить как есть, и у Вас всё равно возникает проблема при запуске приложения, но позже всё ок. Я бы сделал splash screen при запуске в отдельном потоке, пока подгружается разметка основного экрана, и анимировал бы загрузку в зависимости от видимости View элементов вашего "тяжелого" layout, когда счетчик бы доходил до макс кол-ва существующих элементов layout, сбрасывал бы SplashScreen и загружал основной activity с "тяжелой" разметкой.

Comment: Я могу предположить, что виноват ваш планшет. Если он относится к категории очень бюджетных, то такой вариант возможен, и никуда вы от него не денетесь. Не ожидайте одинакового пользовательского опыта на флагмане и на бюджетном девайсе.
Если же нет, то тогда вы напортачили в разметке, причём крайне серьёзно. Не видя кода невозможно сделать более подробных заключений.

Comment: Может вы приложите код разметки, так было-бы проще дать ответ, а не занимается лечением по фотогоафии,  может там и не в разметке дело.

Comment: никак. СОздание иерархии `View` возможно только в главном потоке. Проблема скорее вего в в ашей разметке

Comment: Код разметки очень велик, не зря он столько грузится (приложение — игра). Спешу заверить — написан он наиболее оптимально, насколько это представляется возможным. Меньше элементов сделать никак нельзя. Так неужели нельзя на нативном Андроиде каким угодно образом что-то отображать, пока грузится разметка в setContentView()? Подойдёт даже статичное изображение.

Comment: Если отображаются не все элементы, либо первоначально какие либо элементы находятся в статусе ```Invisible/Gone```, то можно попробовать разбить разметку на несколько элементов, и каждый элемент обернуть во ```ViewStub```, тогда он будет просчитываться только в момент когда он станет видимым, либо вызовется метод ```inflate``` - http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html

Answer (score 1):

Пришлось костылировать, делая в разметке у всех элементов `android:visibility="gone"`, а затем писать класс, инициализирующий все View, устанавливающий на них необходимую информацию и выставляющий им видимость, отправляя текущий прогресс загрузки в метод для обновления специального TextView, отображающего процент загрузки.

Если есть у кого идеи получше — буду рад их услышать.